# Powershell CSV removing rows and then remove from whole file if A column matches

Tags: powershell, scripting

I've created the following small script to remove 2++ strings from a CSV.
Each row is a log of a given person and a answer they give.
The CSV has X columns.
The column named FIRST identifies the person.

What I need to do is when I delete a row matching the answer, I also need to delete the person from the whole CSV if it had one of the two strings.

What I've made so far, removes the row of people having the answers but the person is still left in the overall CSV with other answers. I want to remove the person fully if the questions have been answered.

Can somebody help me out with making the addition or changes to make this happen?

**INPUT File**

```
FIRST,LAST,ADDR,ADDR2,GENDER,HOME,WORK
1,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,BAF,N/A
10005,JAS,AA,N/A,,ZAV,N/A
10007,JADE,BB,N/A,OMA,N/A,N/A
10007,JADE,N/A,RAV,N/A,N/A,N/A
10011,KIAH,N/A,N/A,BALI,BB,N/A
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$CSVfile = "C:\Temp\Test\Test.csv"
$CSVfile_filtered = "C:\Temp\Test\Test.csv"

$regex001 = "AA"
$regex002 = "BB"


$filterArray = @($regex001,$regex002)
Get-Content $CSVfile | Select-String -pattern $filterArray -notmatch | Set-Content $CSVfile_filtered
```

The file should then remove 10005, 10011 and both lines of 10007. But my version only removes one of the 10007 since it only matches one of the two patterns.

Comment: please add a sample of the input file & the desired output from that input. you can limit things to just 5 or 6 lines - and sanitize things as needed. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey updated it with the file. It's not very complicated, but my head just can't get around it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`?

Comment: @Olaf no reason. Just what I thought of how to do it initially.

Comment: @user15779222 - thank you for the added info! [*grin*] it looks like AdminOfThings has provided an Answer that covers your needs. the use of `Group-Object` is really nifty ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using more of PowerShell's built-in cmdlets can make this a little easier to manage.

```
# Assuming searching only properties ADDR and ADDR2
$filter = 'AA','BB'
# Grouping by First and Last values to easily remove duplicates
# -match uses regex so | is needed for an OR of multiple items
Import-Csv Test.csv | Group-Object First,Last |
    Where {!($_.Group.ADDR,$_.Group.ADDR2 -match ($filter -join '|'))} |
        Foreach-Object Group |
            Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

---

You would think strictly using text manipulation would be simpler, but it adds other scenarios to consider:

1. You will need to track users that have duplicate entries and potentially back track to remove them (if not grouping). This could require reading the file contents twice.
2. Your header row could match the string you want to filter so you will need to add it to the output if filtering removes it.

Keeping the scenarios above in mind, you can still use a grouping concept:

```
$filter = 'AA','BB'
$file = Get-Content Test.csv
# $file[0] is the header row
# -split string uses regex and splits at the second comma
# -split results' [0] element is First,Last values
$file[0],($file |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        Group-Object {($_ -split '(?<=^[^,]*,[^,]*),')[0]} |
            where {!($_.Group -match ($filter -join '|'))} |
                Foreach-Object Group) | Set-Content output.csv
```

Comment: Very nice! Seems to work. At least how I understood the question. ;-)

Comment: This solves it! But how do I do it if a column is having a space in it?
Like Home Address.
I tried $_.Group."Home Address" but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `$_.Group.'Home Address'` would be the correct syntax if that is indeed a column name.

Comment: Tried the following on this line:
`where {!($_.Group.'Home Address' -match ($filter -join '|'))} |`
But the filtered line doesn't get removed. I do get a sorted and grouped CSV file, but the filtered values are still in there on the given column. I'm using the last example code you provided, the one with split.

Comment: What does `$filter` contain in your code?

Comment: `$filter = 'AA','BB'` So I want to limit it to column 'Home Address' in this one file I have. The code is exactly the same as above with just adding `.'Home Address'` to the `$_.Group`

Comment: @user15779222 I'd need to see sample file contents then.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I found the issue, but don't know how to mitigate it. If I run the script twice on the file but on the second one I add `.'Home Address` it will not work since the file is already grouped by the first column. If I just change the order of two rows, it works. How to also make it work if everything is already pre-sorted?

Comment: @user15779222 The purpose of `group-object` is to group your duplicates of `First` and `Last`. If there are rows where `First` and `Last` don't match among two or more rows, then they won't be grouped together. Is the problem that the order of your file is changed once the script runs? If your file looks different than what you posted, then there will be problems. Are you using the first example of code or the second one? I'd still like to see a sample of the lines/rows that do not work.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I run the script twice. But with 2 different filters.
The first time it creates a group/sorted output. If I run the script on the same file for the second time by altering the filter and limiting it to `.'Home Address'` nothing happens. It seems to be the case since the first run grouped and sorted it.

Comment: @user15779222 The first run may remove some rows because of the filtering. If you run it again on the filtered file, then stuff from the original file will undoubtedly be missing. I did a test running against your test file just to do sorting and saving it. Then I ran with filtering against the saved file, and I get the correct results. If you are changing the filter, then you must ensure that it is regex escaped. In your example, you filtered `AA` and `BB`. If you are filtering for something like `RT. 12`, then you must backslash escape the `.` --> `RT\. 12`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you could do something like this:

```
$SearchPattern = 'AA', 'BB'

$INPUTCSV = @'
FIRST,LAST,ADDR,ADDR2,GENDER,HOME,WORK
1,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,BAF,N/A
10005,JAS,AA,N/A,,ZAV,N/A
10007,JADE,BB,N/A,OMA,N/A,N/A
10007,JADE,N/A,RAV,N/A,N/A,N/A
10011,KIAH,N/A,N/A,BALI,BB,N/A
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv 


$ActualSearchPattern =
$INPUTCSV | 
Where-Object {
    $_.LAST -in $SearchPattern -or
    $_.ADDR -in $SearchPattern -or
    $_.ADDR2 -in $SearchPattern -or
    $_.GENDER -in $SearchPattern -or
    $_.HOME -in $SearchPattern -or
    $_.Work -in $SearchPattern
} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FIRST

$INPUTCSV | 
Where-Object -Property FIRST -NotIn -Value $ActualSearchPattern |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

There might be more sophisticated or more elegant ways but I cannot think about one at the moment.  ;-)

Comment: This gives the same outcome as my initial script. The problem is line 5, which is the duplicated one from JADE but missing the BB and AA. What I want is:
IF a row has BB or AA delete this row and all rows with the same FIRST column input.
So here, remove all 10007 since line 4 matched.

Comment: Ah ... now I got it ... I think ... let me think about it .........   ;-)

Comment: It almost works as I need it, but the current version requires the AA and BB to be in the ADDR column. But it might be in any of the other columns except the FIRST.

Comment: You like to make it hard, don't you? ;-)   Try it now. ( I just hope you don't have actually much more columns than you showed here in your sample data)

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice PowerShell module you can use to manipulate the content of a csv or xlsx file: [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.1)

This give you a lot of options to manipulate the sheets, columns etc.

Comment: PowerShell is easily able to deal with structured data in CSV files out of the box. No additional module needed.  ;-)